# Check if the last characters in a string or inputs are similar to each other in javascript

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm trying to create a simple add calculator. As of now I am successful on displaying the numbers and concatenating them. But I what I don't want is when I clicked the plus(add) button two or more times, it will also concatenate with another plus symbol. Is there a way for me that if ever I clicked the plus button twice. the second symbol will no longer display. Like if it detects that the previous input is a plus symbol. it will never concatenate with each other. Sorry if my English is not clear.

Sample Error when i clicked the add button multiple times: ( 111++++222 ) instead of just 111+222

Here's my code guys:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>


  <style>

    body {

      margin: 0px auto;
      width: 600px;
    }
  p {

    font-size: 23px;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px;
    border: solid #336336 2px;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <h1 id="result">aaww </h1>


  <p id="1" class="one">1</p>
  <p id="2" class="two">2</p>


  </br></br>

  <p id="add">+</p>


  </br></br>

  <p id="equals">=</p>
 <!--  <p class="cancel">cancel</p> <p class="cancel">cancel</p> -->

  <p class="clear-tasks"> CLEAR</p>

  <script>


    //PLACE HOLDER FOR THE RESULT
    let Result = document.getElementById("result");
    Result.innerText = "RESULT HERE";

    // CLEAR BUTTON
    let clear = document.querySelector('.clear-tasks'); 
    // EVENT LISTENER TO CLEAR THE BUTTON
    clear.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
      Result.textContent = '';
    });

    let addition = document.querySelector("#add");
    addition.addEventListener('click',runEventAdd);
    function runEventAdd(e){
      Result.textContent += ' + ';
    }

    

    //ONE BUTTON
    const numberOne = document.querySelector('.one');

    // EVENT LISTENER TO CONCATINATE 1
    numberOne.addEventListener('click', runEvent);

    function runEvent(e) {
      if (Result.textContent === 'RESULT HERE') {
        Result.textContent = 1;
      } else {Result.textContent += 1;
      }
    }

    
     //TWO BUTTON
    const numberTwo = document.querySelector('.two');
    // EVENT LISTENER TO CONCATINATE 2
    numberTwo.addEventListener('click', runEvent2);

    function runEvent2(e) {
      if (Result.textContent === 'RESULT HERE') {
        Result.textContent = 2;
      } else {Result.textContent += 2;
      }
    }


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you concatenating numbers?  They shouldn't be strings.

Comment: Just save the last input to a variable and check if its a plus.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Sir you mean it should be a string?

Comment: @JackOfAllTrades I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish.  Eventually you'll be casting your concatenated string to a Number for the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) to check if the current string ends with a +:

```
addition.addEventListener('click',runEventAdd);
function runEventAdd(e){
  if (!Result.textContent.endsWith(' + '))
      Result.textContent += ' + ';
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Did not know that there is such object.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` statement to check if there is already an operator. I made something similar in Java with GUI instead of JS but thats what I did and it worked fine. If you do the `if` statement you could use `if(str.indexOf(operator) == -1) {
do the concatenation`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the last value of your result. If it is a '+', don't add another '+'

```js
    
    //PLACE HOLDER FOR THE RESULT
    let Result = document.getElementById("result");
    Result.innerText = "RESULT HERE";

    // CLEAR BUTTON
    let clear = document.querySelector('.clear-tasks'); 
    // EVENT LISTENER TO CLEAR THE BUTTON
    clear.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
      Result.textContent = '';
    
    });

    let addition = document.querySelector("#add");
    addition.addEventListener('click',runEventAdd);
    function runEventAdd(e){

      if(Result.innerText.slice(-1) != '+')
      {
      Result.textContent += ' + ';
      }
      
    
    }

    

    //ONE BUTTON
    const numberOne = document.querySelector('.one');

    // EVENT LISTENER TO CONCATINATE 1
    numberOne.addEventListener('click', runEvent);

    function runEvent(e) {
      if (Result.textContent === 'RESULT HERE') {
        Result.textContent = 1;
      } else {Result.textContent += 1;
      }
    }

    
  //TWO BUTTON
 const numberTwo = document.querySelector('.two');
    // EVENT LISTENER TO CONCATINATE 2
    numberTwo.addEventListener('click', runEvent2);

    function runEvent2(e) {
      if (Result.textContent === 'RESULT HERE') {
        Result.textContent = 2;
      } else {Result.textContent += 2;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>


  <style>

    body {

      margin: 0px auto;
      width: 600px;
    }
  p {

    font-size: 23px;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px;
    border: solid #336336 2px;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <h1 id="result">aaww </h1>


  <p id="1" class="one">1</p>
  <p id="2" class="two">2</p>


  </br></br>

  <p id="add">+</p>


  </br></br>

  <p id="equals">=</p>
 <!--  <p class="cancel">cancel</p> <p class="cancel">cancel</p> -->

  <p class="clear-tasks"> CLEAR</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the alternative answer Sir! You rock!